# Windows 7 / Linux Dual Boot Chkdsk Everytime

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot

I have a problem with a dual boot win7/linux system.

Every time I boot in Linux, and then boot into win7, I have the annoying problem of windows 7 running a check disk.

Initially I dismissed it as user error, but since switching from a Ubuntu dual setup to a Fedora dual setup and I have the exact same problem: Every time I exit Linux and reboot into Windows 7 it runs a CHDSK. Now is Fedora perhaps changing a part of the drive that windows expects to remain the same? If I could track it down it may help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let the `CHKDSK` operation finish
2. `CHKDSK` will reboot the machine
3. Boot into Windows 7
4. Cleanly reboot the system from within Windows 7
5. Boot into Linux
6. Cleanly reboot the system from within Linux
7. Boot into Windows 7

`CHKDSK` should *not* run at this point.

Be aware that if you are mounting your Windows partition from within Linux, you need be sure to unmount it when you're finished using it.  `CHKDSK` may be kicking off as a result of improperly shutting down Ubuntu while your Windows partition is mounted (and/or in use).