# Stop chkdsk when Windows 7 on one drive and Windows 8 on another

Tags: multi-boot, windows-8, chkdsk

I installed Windows 8 (retail) on a new drive with my Windows 7 drive unplugged. So each Windows has no idea about the other one and I use the BIOS boot options to select which drive hence OS to boot into.

Now whenever I boot into Windows 8 then boot into Windows 7, Windows 7 runs chkdisk presumably because Windows 8 messed with it.

Is there anyway to stop this? (In hindsight I should have installed Windows 8 with Windows 7 drive plugged in so I could use the Windows dual boot options).

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/464259/windows-7-linux-dual-boot-chkdsk-everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you may use `CHKNTFS.EXE`. [Download link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160963). An excerpt from its docs:

> The Chkntfs.exe utility has been developed by Microsoft [...]. It is designed to **disable the automatic running of chkdsk** on specific volumes, when Windows restarts from an improper shutdown. Chkntfs can also be used to unschedule a chkdsk if chkdsk /f was used to schedule a chkdsk on an active volume on the next system restart.

Yet another solution is checking whether Windows 8 is **indeed** shutting down, not hybernating to a "hybrid boot". [This thread](http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/5482-windows-8-cp-check-disk-dual-boot.html) helped me for CTP, but frankly I have not tested it against the retail version.

Comment: Thanks. My concern with disabling chkdsk is should there be genuine reason for it running it will not! Whether Windows 8 is shutting down or not I would hope I could leave it to do its thing - if it does hybird boot by default I would like to have my cake and eat it.

Comment: Unless shut down properly, Windows marks volumes with a "dirty" flag. With hybrid boot, Windows 8 leaves this flag. If you start into Windows 7, it sees dirty flag, but it does not know **which** system has put this flag; it simply thinks it has not been shut down properly and runs `CHKDSK`. The only way to avoid running disk check is proper shutdown of all systems you have. Or disabling the check **at your own risk**.

Comment: thanks. btw: I re-installed Windows 8 with my Windows 7 drive plugged in so I now get the Windows 8 dual boot options to select which OS I want to boot into.